Make input device (mouse) "unavailable" to desktop
What I am looking for is a way to prevent a pointer device (specifically the pen of a graphics tablet) from being used as a regular input pointer by X11 or Wayland. However, I would like to still be able to evaluate clicks and moves in my program. So basically tie the output of that pen to my application, ideally regardless of whether it has focus or not.
Under X11, devices can be set "floating", which prevents these from being used as generic input device, but I am not sure whether the same can be done in Wayland and how.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Have you tried xinput
xinput will output a list of input devices to X
example output
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4   [slave pointer  (2)]
↳ USB Optical Mouse id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
then use 'xinput -disable 8' to disable the optical mouse for X
You will be able to recieve the input from /dev/input/event* files, e.g. trying 'evtest' utility
for your application!
For wayland, there seems to be similar utilities, see for example
the commands sway-input or maybe libinput, (but I could only find a disable function for sway-input...)

under X11, this works. But under wayland, I don't see the individual pointer devices using xinput. And with libinput, I can't create logical seats (or don't know how).
